# What is the advantage of registering a Vue component locally?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

The [documentation from Vue](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-registration.html#Local-Registration) says:

> Global registration often isn’t ideal. For example, if you’re using a
> build system like Webpack, globally registering all components means
> that even if you stop using a component, it could still be included in
> your final build. This unnecessarily increases the amount of
> JavaScript your users have to download.

If I'm understanding this correctly, using local registration doesn't decrease overall file size unless you forget to delete any unused components.  If you register a component locally, that component still gets pulled into your main JS file (if it didn't, then you wouldn't be able to use the component even locally as the code would be undefined).

This leaves me with quite the edge case for using local registration - to make sure you don't forget to delete the global component registration if you stop using a component.  Of course, it's also possible to forget to delete the local registration if you stop using a component, in which case you'd have the same problem even with local registration.

It seems like the main use case for local registration is to ensure a component can not be used elsewhere.  I'm trying to think of what dangers that would prevent against?

Comment: Besides @Jeff's good reasons, you may also want to lazy load some parts of the app, so those components should be declared locally not globally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's nice and clean for when you only need a component in one place. ie. registering `NavBar` in your `Header` component because it will never be used elsewhere, and it gives you a quick way to navigate to that component through your IDE.

It avoids collisions if you have two components with the same name, like maybe from two third-party components named `vue-button` and you need them both in different places.

I bet there are some very small performance gains too since your Vue instance doesn't register the component until its used, although thats more speculation and likely insignificant

At the end of the day I think it's more about compartmentalizing your code in relevant groups and just helps with organization.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, Jeff